# skype crashing when other contact logs on

Tags: skype

I was in a video call with someone, and I would receive a notification that somebody else has logged on. a second or so later, skype would crash. I have checked for updates, and there were none. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Ubuntu documentation for Skype....

> Installing Skype
>
> Users of 64-bit Ubuntu, should enable MultiArch if it isn't already
>   enabled by running the command
>
> `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
>
> Since Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx), Skype is part of the Canonical
>   partner repository. To install Skype add the Canonical Partner
>   Repository. You can do this by running the command

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/
> $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

> Then install Skype via the Software-Center or via the Terminal.
>
> `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype`
>
> It is highly recommended to use the package provided in the Canonical
>   partner repository, not the one distributed from the skype website, as
>   the skype website currently points users to the wrong package for
>   64-bit systems of Ubuntu 11.10 and above.

I just tried it, seems to work, i had the same issue as you, i hope it is not a temporary solution

Answer (score 1):

If you downloaded from with Software Manager or Synaptic or apt-get, you may have issues.  I've always have, so I go to the site and have better success.

1. Go here:
   http://beta.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/
2. From the site drop down menu, and choose dynamic.
3. Extract to your home directory.
4. Open terminal and navigate to the Skype directory.
5. type `./skype`
6. Enjoy, I think you will have better results.